# MPNS messages are not working

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, cordova-plugins, mpns, phonegap-pushplugin

I have made a windows phone 8.1 application using cordova(Phonegap).
I am using PushPlugin for notification. It works perfectly fine for Android and iOS, but for Windows phone 8.1 it doesn't work. Actually it works randomly.

I am using Toast notification for windows. So some times I receive toast notification; some times I don't.

I am successfully generating channel and registering at MPNS. Notification URI is something like given below.

```
http://s.notify.live.net/u/1/sin/H2QAAAAVvWfCaYxRXqTAKuMvkQn........
```

- CASE I.

  Server side implementation is in PHP. When I receive Toast Notification on windows device, response at server is

  ```
  [HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Cache-Control: private
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-Server: RD000D3A107A1E
  X-DeviceConnectionStatus: Connected
  X-NotificationStatus: Received
  X-SubscriptionStatus: Active
  X-MessageID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  Date: Wed, 06 May 2015 11:00:45 GMT
  Content-Length: 0]
  ```
- CASE II.

  But when I don't receive a Toast notification, response at server is

  ```
  Blank Array( [] )
  ```

  I am wondering why response is blank array instead of any proper response as described above.

I have tried both cases with  Wifi and Data Connection, but result is the same.

Comment: Are you testing it on the emulator? However WNS is more reliable at this time

Comment: yes im testing it on emulator and device...

Comment: Then don't lose time on emulator, push notifications won't work there, no matter what you do.

Comment: Any success? That message `Blank Array` is probably some server issue. You could retag your question.

Comment: I suggest you to go through this thread. It is described what you are looking in detail.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354023/setting-up-wns-service-for-windows-phone-8-get-error-after-add-identity-tag/31365503#31365503