# Setting up WNS service for windows phone 8 get error after add <Identity> tag

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, urbanairship.com, wns, windows-dev-center

I am setting up windows phone 8.1 push notification with urbanairship. I have SID and Secret key for my app. But when i do following step mentioned in dev.windows WNS-->Live Service site:

> To set your application's identity values manually, open the
>   AppManifest.xml file in a text editor and set these attributes of the
>    element using the values shown here.

my application is stop working. is any one provide me steps for set up WNS in windows phone 8.1 then it helps me a lot, I spend over the week on this and now really frustrating.

Comment: You don't need to do anything in AppManifest.xml. You just need Client ID, and Client Secret to get your work done.

Comment: no it won't work. i gone through some steps and download visual studio 2013 and open in that. it works but some reference are missing so still not working wns.

Comment: I have done it successfully. Please go through the answer. Let me know if you have any confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got success with Push Notification in Windows Phone 8.1/ Windows Apps (Universal Apps). I have implemented sending Push Notification to devices from our own Web Service.

**Step 1**: Get the **Client Secret** and **Package SID** from the dev.windows.com >> Services >> Live Services. You'll need these later in Web Service.

**Step 2**: In your Windows App, you have to associate your app with the Store. For that, Right click on project >> Store >> Associate App with the Store. Log in with your Dev account and associate your app.
[image: Associating your app with the Store]

**Step 3**
You'll need a Channel Uri.
In the MainPage.xaml, add a Button and a Textblock to get your Channel Uri.
XAML Code looks like this:

```
<Page
x:Class="FinalPushNotificationTest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:FinalPushNotificationTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Push Notification" Margin="20,48,10,0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,10,10,0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="resultsPanel">
            <Button x:Name="PushChannelBtn" Content="Get Channel Uri" Click="PushChannelBtn_Click" />
            <ProgressBar x:Name="ChannelProgress" IsIndeterminate="False" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ChannelText" FontSize="22" />

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**Step 4**:
In the MainPage.xaml.cs page, Add the following code snippet i.e. for the Button Click Event. When you run your app, you'll get the **Channel Uri** in the Console Window. Note down this Channel Uri, you'll need that in Web Service.

```
private async void PushChannelBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
        ChannelText.Text = channel.Uri.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(channel.Uri);
    }
```

[image: Channel Uri]

**Step 5:**
Now You need a Web Service to send push notification to your device. For that Right Click on your project in Solution Explorer. Add >> New Project >> Visual C# >> Web >> ASP.NET Web Application. Click OK, On Template select Empty. After that Add a new **Web Form** in your Web Application. Name it **SendToast**.
[image: Adding a new Web project to your project]
[image: Selecting Empty Template for your Web Project]
[image: Adding Web Form in your Web Application]

**Step 6:**
Now In the **SendToast.aspx.cs**, you need to implement methods and functions to get the **Access Token** using Package SID, Client Secret and Channel Uri. Add your Package SID, Cleint Secret, and Channel Uriin respective places.
The complete code looks like the following code snippet:

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SendToast
{
    public partial class SendToast : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string sid = "Your Package SID";
        private string secret = "Your Client Secret";
        private string accessToken = "";
    [DataContract]
    public class OAuthToken
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }
    }

    OAuthToken GetOAuthTokenFromJson(string jsonString)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OAuthToken));
            var oAuthToken = (OAuthToken)ser.ReadObject(ms);
            return oAuthToken;
        }
    }

    public void getAccessToken()
    {
        var urlEncodedSid = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Format("{0}", this.sid));
        var urlEncodedSecret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.secret);

        var body =
          String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=notify.windows.com", urlEncodedSid, urlEncodedSecret);

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        string response = client.UploadString("https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf", body);
        var oAuthToken = GetOAuthTokenFromJson(response);
        this.accessToken = oAuthToken.AccessToken;
    }

    protected string PostToCloud(string uri, string xml, string type = "wns/toast")
    {
        try
        {
            if (accessToken == "")
            {
                getAccessToken();
            }
            byte[] contentInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

            WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            HttpWebRequest request = webRequest as HttpWebRequest;
            webRequest.Method = "POST";

            webRequest.Headers.Add("X-WNS-Type", type);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));

            Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(contentInBytes, 0, contentInBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            return webResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {
            string exceptionDetails = webException.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"];
            if ((exceptionDetails != null) && exceptionDetails.Contains("Token expired"))
            {
                getAccessToken();
                return PostToCloud(uri, xml, type);
            }
            else
            {
                return "EXCEPTION: " + webException.Message;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string channelUri = "Your Channel Uri";

        if (Application["channelUri"] != null)
        {
            Application["channelUri"] = channelUri;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Add("channelUri", channelUri);
        }

        if (Application["channelUri"] != null)
        {
            string aStrReq = Application["channelUri"] as string;
            string toast1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> ";
            string toast2 = @"<toast>
                        <visual>
                            <binding template=""ToastText01"">
                                <text id=""1"">Hello Push Notification!!</text>
                            </binding>
                        </visual>
                    </toast>";
            string xml = toast1 + toast2;

            Response.Write("Result: " + PostToCloud(aStrReq, xml));
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Application 'channelUri=' has not been set yet");
        }
        Response.End();
    }
  }
}
```

Run your web application, you'll get the **Result OK** response if it successfully sends push notification.

Let me know if you need working sample project. 
Hope this helps.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi kishor, thanks for your answer. But i am working with windows phone 8.1 and sending notification from urbanairship. I set up clinet secret and sid in my windiws app. And trying to send notification from urbanairship they show me status sent successfully but not getting in windows phone

Comment: Oh its ok. Can you explain in bit more detail about the urbanairship?

Comment: you can go through http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/windows.html#windows-8-8-1-windows-phone-8-1 for windows urbanairship configuration

Comment: Hi @kishor Bikkram Oli, Thanks for you wonderful answer, it's give me inspire to write code at server side, i did it and it's works like charm. I used Java servlet at my server side.

Comment: @KishorBikramOli  Iam also getting "OK" response. but I am not getting any notification to my device.Is there any changes to my device please help me.

Comment: @KishorBikramOli see my code on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762118/pushnotification-not-getting-in-windows-phone-app-8-1 link

Comment: @KishorBikramOli is there any changes in my device settings,please help me.

Comment: Iam doing this pushnotifications  for last 3 days till now I am not getting any response.

Comment: There is unusual format of xml for your **badge** notifications.