# How to send pushnotifications in windows phone 8.1 runtime app (not silverlight)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone app, In this app I want to develop send  `pushnotifications for devices.`

Below is my code

string subscriptionUri = "http://s.notify.live.net/u/1/hk2/H2QAAADrEJ2fJgP0eNwNQ5Xp139q1mNu9TCpEwwxjX6j1";
    var sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri);

```
// Create an HTTPWebRequest that posts the toast notification to the Microsoft Push Notification Service.
// HTTP POST is the only method allowed to send the notification.
sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

// The optional custom header X-MessageID uniquely identifies a notification message. 
// If it is present, the same value is returned in the notification response. It must be a string that contains a UUID.
// sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-MessageID", "<UUID>");

// Create the toast message.
var toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
   "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
      "<wp:Toast>" +
           "<wp:Text1>" + message + "</wp:Text1>" +
      "</wp:Toast> " +
   "</wp:Notification>";
// Set the notification payload to send.

byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toastMessage);

// Set the web request content length.
sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");

using (var requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
}

// Send the notification and get the response.
var response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
var notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
var notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
var deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

// Display the response from the Microsoft Push Notification Service.  
// Normally, error handling code would be here. In the real world, because data connections are not always available,
// notifications may need to be throttled back if the device cannot be reached.
var rep = notificationStatus + " | " + deviceConnectionStatus + " | " + notificationChannelStatus;
return rep;
```

Above code I am sending my deviceid for the

string subscriptionUri = "http://s.notify.live.net/u/1/hk2/H2QAAADrEJ2fJgP0eNwNQ5Xp139q1mNu9TCpEwwxjX6j1"

```
var sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri);

// Create an HTTPWebRequest that posts the toast notification to the Microsoft Push Notification Service.
// HTTP POST is the only method allowed to send the notification.
sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

// The optional custom header X-MessageID uniquely identifies a notification message. 
// If it is present, the same value is returned in the notification response. It must be a string that contains a UUID.
// sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-MessageID", "<UUID>");

// Create the toast message.
var toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
   "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
      "<wp:Toast>" +
           "<wp:Text1>" + message + "</wp:Text1>" +
      "</wp:Toast> " +
   "</wp:Notification>";
// Set the notification payload to send.

byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toastMessage);

// Set the web request content length.
sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");

using (var requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
}

// Send the notification and get the response.
var response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
var notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
var notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
var deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

// Display the response from the Microsoft Push Notification Service.  
// Normally, error handling code would be here. In the real world, because data connections are not always available,
// notifications may need to be throttled back if the device cannot be reached.
var rep = notificationStatus + " | " + deviceConnectionStatus + " | " + notificationChannelStatus;
return rep;
```

But whenever comes to response its throwing error.(400 error).

I am getting SubscriptionUri from below code:

```
var channelOperation = Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

Please help me. How to `send pushnotifications for the devices.` ?

Comment: Are you try to `send notification` from `Device to Device` ? As I understand your posted Question.

Comment: How did you get the subscriptionUri? Have you called channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync() on the device to register it for push notifications?

Comment: @Jogy yes.I am using above method.but I didn't register any where.where should I register.

Comment: pleas tell me anybody how should I register to device for pushnotifications

Comment: @Jogy please tell me how to register to device

Comment: Calling CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync() is what creates the channel and registers for push notifications

Comment: Please refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354023/setting-up-wns-service-for-windows-phone-8-get-error-after-add-identity-tag/31365503#31365503