# Push Notification not getting in windows phone app 8.1RT?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing sending push notifications, everything is working fine and response is also getting "OK". But I could not get any notification. Are there any changes on my device settings? Please help me.

Below is my code:

I am getting channeluri from this code:

```
 var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
 var jj = channel.Uri.ToString();
```

My service code is:

```
string subscriptionUri = "https://hk2.notify.windows.com/?token=rretetretretretretretrergtrgtrgtrg43589743cn43jr43jr43jr4rvr43ro045jv77nninuoinjyt";

string PushNotificationXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                             "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                             "<wp:Tile>" + "<wp:BackgroundImage>" + "sdfsafdsafsdf" +
                             "</wp:BackgroundImage>" + "<wp:Count>" + 
                             "0" + "</wp:Count>" + "<wp:Title>" +
                             "Hi This is pavan" + "</wp:Title>" +
                             "</wp:Tile> " + "</wp:Notification>";

string strChannelURI = subscriptionUri;

//string secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
//string sid = "ms-app://s-1-15-2-23454435445-4343434-4343434443434-343434343-334-343443434-3434344443";
var accessToken = GetAccessToken(secret, sid);

byte[] contentInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PushNotificationXML);

HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("X-WNS-Type", "wns/badge");
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken.AccessToken));

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    requestStream.Write(contentInBytes, 0, contentInBytes.Length);

using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    webResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
```

Response is "OK" but i could not get any notification to the my device.

Comment: You are trying to send badge right? Try sending toast first. **wns/toast** and the xml should be like: `string toast1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> ";
            string toast2 = @"<toast>
                        <visual>
                            <binding template=""ToastText01"">
                                <text id=""1"">Hello Push Notification!!</text>
                            </binding>
                        </visual>
                    </toast>";
            string xml = toast1 + toast2;
`

Comment: If it works: try `<badge value="12"/>` for **wns/badge**

Comment: @KishorBikramOli  Thank you for your response.I will try and tell you.

Comment: @KishorBikramOli I am replace badge to toast but not getting notification to my device.

Comment: @KishorBikramOli or give any permissions in  appmanifestfile

Comment: @KishorBikramOli   string subscriptionUri = "https://hk2.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAAAqksei6yWvmlcV8RmESRNrXotwCWV0AY9PSOtmgpIo%2bNwq67tkYjG7450r%2bUKpLwxri%2bO7Re9%2f8qmZDAc3TmTlMOaONVqq9ogCKONX2oWe%2fVq%2bT9tIxEllJW3tnKJEfNM%3d";
            string subscriptionUri = "http://s.notify.live.net/u/1/hk2/H2QAAACfgMkOSS8jNp_XgLamnXFqQrk6g8L6pRJHsQxvppe8-lD4EgCu8LcwdtuDIGnY78tjyaL1lsFxLjWl5s-Sgum5tjBQMk-9emm73LJa9125iECyFCoPb5erRBRwGAgNv2o/d2luZG93c3Bob25lZGVmYXVsdA/jGFxihnYNUOIt5Q4gABT7Q/T4l1SvWZqMi_mEe4F61sx-CINOg";

Comment: @KishorBikramOli above comment two urls is there.1st url is windows RT app.second one is silverlightapp.I am getting notification for silverlight app url.but I want to get notification for windows RTapp uri.what should i do

Comment: Your above xml format will not work for WinRT apps. That works only for Silverlight apps or WP8 apps.

Comment: Have you tried for **wns/toast** that I suggested earlier?

Comment: @KishorBikramOli please see my   this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414484/push-notification-error-in-windows-phone-8-1-rt

Comment: @KishorBikramOli please help me